# php use get function in form

Tags: php, mysql, forms, get

I would like to thank everyone helping me on my previous question.  This is the last question i have.  Currently i have my program running but i just need to figure out how to use the get function on check boxes and text boxes.

Here is the updated form that i am using as an example:

```
<form name="phoenix" method="post" action="">
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","ericjw3160","Taker3160","Database3160");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$table = "phoenix";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE id = :id";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
?>

<table width="1100" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
  <td  width="1100" height="1550" style="background-image:url(../test%20report%20page/images/city%20of%20phx%20Test%20report%20large.jpg); background-repeat:no-repeat; width:1100px; height:1550px;" valign="top"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <td width="62" height="204">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="961">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="77">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="37">&nbsp;</td>
      <td valign="bottom"><table width="100%" height="40" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
          <td width="335" height="40" align="right"><div style="padding_left:110px; padding_bottom:5px;"><?php echo $result["water_purveyor"]; ?></div></td>
          <td width="295" align="right"><div style="padding_bottom:5px;"><?php echo $meter_num ?></div></td>
          <td width="249" align="right"><div style="padding_bottom:5px;"><?php echo $permit_num ?></div></td>
        </tr>
      </table></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="37">&nbsp;</td>
      <td valign="bottom"><table width="100%" height="34" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
          <td width="38%" height="34" align="right"><?php echo $manufacturer ?></td>
          <td width="17%" align="right"><?php echo $meter_size ?></td>
          <td width="17%" align="right"><?php echo $model_num ?></td>
          <td width="28%" align="right"><?php echo $serial_num ?></td>
        </tr>
<tr>
              <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
              <td width="16%" valign="top"><input type="checkbox" name="new_assembly_yes" id="new_assembly_yes" value="1" <?php echo ($result["new_assembly_yes"] ? "checked" : ""); ?> /></td>
              <td width="18%"><input type="checkbox" name="new_assembly_no" id="new_assembly_no" value="1" <?php echo ($result["new_assembly_no"] ? "checked" : ""); ?> /></td>
            </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Instead of using text boxes i just want to display the text, then for the check boxes i have used the result for php code.

Again thank you for all your help.
E

Comment: Use a single name for a set of checkboxes and name them in an array `[]` format. But why checkboxes? And not instead use radio button? I think you only want one answer for one set.

Comment: The reason for the check boxes is this is a form for a client.  They had it set up this way to allow for multiple choices.

Can you give me an example of the array you are talking about.